# Select item out of multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have searched the site but can't find a solution to my problem.
I want to select only the productnames out the array. (like: flute, trumpet..)

That's my array.

```
 $products = array
    ( 
      'MMS-1754'=> array( 'name'=> 'Flute', 'cost'=> 149.50 ), 
      'MMS-1864'=> array( 'name'=> 'Trumpet','cost' => 199.50 ), 
      'MMS-1965'=> array( 'name'=> 'Clarinet', 'cost'=> 299.50 ) 
    );
```

This is my php code for populating the dropdownlist

```
echo'<select name="Name">'; 
foreach($products as $code => $word)
{
    foreach($word as $product)
    {
        echo'<option value="'.$code.'">'.$product.'</option>';
    }
}

echo'</select>';
```

The result I get are the productnames, but also the costprices. I only want the productnames.

Comment: Use an if statement... I am not sure how this is a question...

Comment: `foreach ($products as $item) { echo $item['name']; }`

Answer (score 6):

You dont need the second foreach. You can access the name directly. The $product value contains the array with name and cost

```
echo'<select name="Name">'; 
foreach($products as $code => $product)
{
    echo'<option value="'.$code.'">'.$product['name'].'</option>';
}
echo'</select>';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo'<select name="Name">'; 
foreach($products as $code => $product)
{
    echo'<option value="'.$code.'">'.$product['name'].'</option>';
}

echo'</select>';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo'<select name="Name">'; 
foreach($products as $code => $word)
{
    echo'<option value="'.$code.'">'.$word['name'].'</option>';
}

echo'</select>';
```

Answer (score 1):

That's easy:

```
echo'<select name="Name">'; 
foreach($products as $code => $product)
{
    echo'<option value="'.$code.'">'.$product['name'].'</option>';
}
echo'</select>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo'<select name="Name">'; 
foreach($products as $code => $word)
{
    echo'<option value="'.$code.'">'.$word['name'].'</option>';
}

echo'</select>';
```